# Zooming Tableviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to zoom in and out a TableView. The TableView is in a View which is inside a ScrollView. The TableView is scrollable but the pinch to zoom isn't working like it works with ImageView.
I would really appreciate if anyone could shed some light to this problem and share a working example.

I have already tried setting min and max zoom for UIScrollView in attribute inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by:

1. first you have to make your table view content size intrinsic by make it subclass the below class.

   ```
   class IntrinsicTableView: UITableView {
   override open var contentSize: CGSize {
       didSet{
           invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
       }
   }
   override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize{
       return contentSize
   }
   ```

   }
2. Then you will stop scrolling of your table view from the storyboard.
3. Then you will configure scroll view to enable zooming.

That's it.